# Pytorch print(x) gives Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch

I am using anaconda python2.7. I was able to install pytorch by using `conda install pytorch` from the installation guide at http://pytorch.org/

When I enter python and test the example

```
from __future__ import print_function
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
x = Variable(torch.ones(2, 2), requires_grad=True) ## works fine
print (x) ## broke here
x ## also broke, python can't give the values stored in x
```

I get the error `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` after the using the `print(x)`.

I am able to do all the pytorch operation on `x` except for printing its value. At some point, I would have to look at the value in `x`. Does anybody have the same problem or know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: It has something to do with your system and/or installation.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the code running when specifying 16Gb memory on my school's server.